# After deployment to Azure Web App: No parameterless constructor defined

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have ASP.NET Web Forms Application (Framework 4.6). The Web App works fine if I deploy to Azure Virtual Machine, Dedicated Windows Server, Local IIS or use "Run" in Visual Studio 2015.

The problem is only exists if I deploy the App to Azure Web Sites.

`Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for type XXX`

I read other explanations here already and I would be glad to add parameterless constructor to this assembly, but unfortunately I don't have the source code of this assembly.

My questions are:

1 Why Web App works well in all environments, but not in Azure Web Sites?

2 Is there any way to solve it?

UPDATE 1

Fortunately I've just got the source of assembly where the error is and added parameterless constructor. It works. I am just wondering now - what would I do if there is no source code of the assembly where the error was? And why the environment of Azure Web-Sites differs from others in this case?

Comment: Check your deployment. Maybe application hasn't been deployed correctly. Create a new app on Azure and try do a fresh deployment. See if it works.

Comment: Checked, tested everything many many many times, otherwise I would not post this question.

Comment: From my simple test, It will not throw error message if we do not define no parameterless constructor. Could provide simple template to reproduce this type issue? The main different between Azure Web app and VM is that Web app runs in a secure environment called a sandbox. it has less permission than Azure VM. Refer to https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox for more details.